# Match values of different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This dataframe is the principal with the original tweets. **"original_ds_.csv"**

```
id              tweet              
---------------------------------------------
78           "onetoone"              
86           "maybe tomorrow"        
72           "thnk you"
```

Then, I extracted the tweet conversation for each tweet. As a result, I have a dataframe called **"threads.csv"**

This dataset represents the conversation tweets extracted from an original tweet

```
id              tweet              conver_id
---------------------------------------------
34           "hello world"            78
36           "nice to have"           78
56           "just an exam"           72
```

-The conver_id is the column which represents the id who started the conversation (extracted from the dataset **original_ds_.csv**)

-The conver_id is the "id" of the original_ds.csv

-It is possible have one or more tweets associated to one original tweet in the dataset as the first.

**Now my question is, how can I do this:**

If the **id** on **original_ds_.csv** is the same in the column **conv_id** of the **threads.csv** add a new column in the **threads.csv** called File_Name with the value SPANISH

Answer (score 0):

The logic is a by strange to me, but if a understand correctly, starting from these dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': list('ABC')}, index=[78,86,72])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'tweet': list('DEF'), 'conver_id': (78,78,12)}, index=(34,36,56))
```

```
>>> df1
   tweet
78     A
86     B
72     C

>>> df2
   tweet  conver_id
34     D         78
36     E         78
56     F         12
```

you can check for each element of `df2['conver_id']` if it is in `df1.index` and map to SPANISH is True:

```
df2['File_Name'] = (np.vectorize({True: 'SPANISH',
                                  False: ''}.get
                                )(df2['conver_id'].isin(df1.index))
                   )
```

output:

```
   tweet  conver_id File_Name
34     D         78   SPANISH
36     E         78   SPANISH
56     F         12
```

If this is not what you want, please update your question with the expected output

Comment: Thank you, I think my example was not clear. I tried to ameliorate what I would like to have in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68513155/11985685

Comment: Please do not start a new question, just edit this one

Comment: Also, it seems that my answer was doing what you expected. Just the non-match value was not defined. Replace the empty string `''` with `'Portugese'`