# Match values of different columns and dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Check if value from one dataframe exists in another dataframe

```
df_threads = pd.DataFrame({'conv_id': ['12', '15', '14', '23'], 'tweets': ['Nice', 'Test', 'Hi', 'Yes']})

df_orig = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['17', '12', '15', '6','67'], 'tweets': ['hola', 'mundo', 'yes', 'look', 'Beautiful']})
```

I would like to know if the value of the column "id" of the dataframe **df_orig** is in the column "conv_id" of **df_threads** and if it is true, add a column "File" in df_threads with the value "Spanish" and if it False set Portuguese.

Expected Output
**df_threads**

```
conv_id         tweet              File
---------------------------------------------
12           "Nice"                "Spanish"
15           "Test"                "Spanish"
14           "Hi"                  "Spanish"
23           "Yes"                 "Spanish"
56           "NotHappy"            "Portuguese"
```

Comment: The data you have doesn't match the output you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match values of different dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512533/match-values-of-different-dataframes)

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.where` and `df.where`:

```
df_threads['File'] = np.where(df_threads['conv_id'].isin(df_orig['id']),
                              'Spanish', 'Portuguese')
```

```
>>> df_threads
  conv_id    tweets        File
0      12      Nice     Spanish
1      15      Test     Spanish
2      14        Hi  Portuguese
3      23       Yes  Portuguese
```

*Note: check your input data and your outcome, they not match.*